# Handling String Literals which End in an Escaped Quote in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

How do I write a lexer rule to match a String literal which does not end in an escaped quote?

Here's my grammar:

```
lexer grammar StringLexer;

// from The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference
STRING: '"' (ESC|.)*? '"';
fragment ESC : '\\"' | '\\\\' ;
```

Here's my java block:

```
String s = "\"\\\""; // looks like "\"
StringLexer lexer = new StringLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(s)); 

Token t = lexer.nextToken();

if (t.getType() == StringLexer.STRING) {
    System.out.println("Saw a String");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Nope");
}
```

This outputs `Saw a String`. Should `"\"` really match `STRING`?

**Edit:** Both 280Z28 and Bart's solutions are great solutions, unfortunately I can only accept one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For properly formed input, the lexer will match the text you expect. However, the use of the non-greedy operator will not prevent it from matching something with the following form:

```
'"' .*? '"'
```

To ensure strings are tokens in the most "sane" way possible, I recommended using the following rules.

```
StringLiteral
  : UnterminatedStringLiteral '"'
  ;

UnterminatedStringLiteral
  : '"' (~["\\\r\n] | '\\' (. | EOF))*
  ;
```

If your language allows string literals to span across multiple lines, you would likely need to modify `UnterminatedStringLiteral` to allow matching end-of-line characters.

If you do not include the `UnterminatedStringLiteral` rule, the lexer will handle unterminated strings by simply ignoring the opening `"` character of the string and proceeding to tokenize the content of the string.

Comment: Is there any reason you made these parser rules instead of lexer rules? I just implemented them as lexer rules and they appear to work fine.

Comment: @RepickBroom They are lexer rules (start with a capital letter). Parser rules start with a lower case letter.

Comment: So much for reading comprehension on my part... I'm used to seeing the all-caps lexer rules; my eyes just glazed over those capitalized rules.

Comment: What was the purpose of splitting rule into two? As I understood, lexer is context-less?

Comment: @Dims I understand its been a few years, but: The lexer goes for the longest possible token, so if you have `"mogusEOF` the lexer will see it as an unterminated string literal. However if you have `"mogus"EOF` then the one extra quote makes StringLiteral the longer token so it is the one that will get tokenized

Answer (score 8):

Yes, `"\"` is matched by the `STRING` rule:

```
            STRING: '"' (ESC|.)*? '"';
                     ^       ^     ^
                     |       |     |
// matches:          "       \     "
```

If you don't want the `.` to match the backslash (and quote), do something like this:

```
STRING: '"' ( ESC | ~[\\"] )* '"';
```

And if your string can't be spread over multiple lines, do:

```
STRING: '"' ( ESC | ~[\\"\r\n] )* '"';
```